# What does "cd &" mean?

Tags: shell, cd-command

I know how to change directory from terminal by typing

```
cd <directory>
```

but here's the scenario. I was using terminal to go on my git repository's folder.

- glennRepositories

  - glenn-remdroid-repository

Given the folder structure above, I want to switch in `glenn-remdroid-repository` because it is my repository by doing.

```
cd glennRepositories
```

Before switching in glenn-remdroid-repository, I mistakenly typed the commmand

```
cd &
```

instead of `cd *`. I used `cd *` because the folder name is long for me, sorry for being lazy.

When I execute the `cd &` , the terminal replies

```
[1] 7519
```

When I execute `cd *` this is now happened

```
[1]+  Done                    cd  (wd: ~/glennRepositories)
(wd now: ~/glennRepositories/glenn-remdroid-repository)
```

Does anyone what `cd &` means and its output? Google doesn't know my question :)

Comment: Something that can't be found with Google is [ogooglebar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogooglebar#Ungoogleable), a Swedish neologism.

Comment: When I type my question, the search result was about Compact disk. Ungoogleable :)

Comment: " I used cd * because the folder name is long for me, sorry for being lazy". Simply type `cd <TAB>` and the name of the unique folder will be expanded automatically.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By writing the `&` on the end of the command line, you are instructing your shell to take the command pipeline (in this case a single command) and run it in a sub-shell in the background (not waiting for a result). `cd` is a bash builtin, but that is not important here. It will not affect your "parent" shell in any way, so your working directory will not be changed.

```
[1] 7519
```

This line is reporting that there is a job running in the background identified by number 1 and the process ID is 7519. A similar thing will be printed if you run e.g. `vim` and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend it. When the process finishes, the shell won't report that until the next processing cycle (e.g. just hit <kbd>Return</kbd> once again) and then it will print the update listing jobs finished.

For further details please read `man bash` and the section `JOB CONTROL`.

For reference, the question [Why does `exit &` not work?](/q/86865) bears some similarity.

Comment: Whether the job end is reported straight away or at the next  prompt depends on the shell. In `fish` and `zsh`, it's reported straight away. In `bash` and other POSIX shells or (t)csh it depends on the setting of the `notify` option (off by default) (`zsh` being a POSIX-like shell also has a `notify` option, but it's off by default unless it's told to emulate another shell)

Answer (score 1):

The `&` operator sends a process to background; as `cd` can be run without arguments you are running it and sending it to background. If you take the man page:

> ### NAME
>
> cd - Change the shell working directory.
>
> ### SYNOPSIS
>
> `cd` [`-L`|`-P`] [*dir*]
>
> ### DESCRIPTION
>
> Change the shell working directory.
>
> Change the current directory to *DIR*.  The default *DIR* is the value of the `HOME` shell variable.
>
> The variable `CDPATH` defines the search path for the directory containing
>       *DIR*.  Alternative directory names in `CDPATH` are separated by a colon (:).
>      A null directory name is the same as the current directory.  If *DIR* begins
>       with a slash (`/`), then `CDPATH` is not used.
>
> If the directory is not found, and the shell option `cdable_vars` is set,
>       the word is assumed to be  a variable name.  If that variable has a value,
>       its value is used for *DIR*.
>
> #### Options:
>
> `-L` force symbolic links to be followed
>      `-P` use the physical directory structure without following symbolic
>           links
>
> The default is to follow symbolic links, as if `-L` were specified.
>
> #### Exit Status:
>
> Returns 0 if the directory is changed; non-zero otherwise.
>
> ### SEE ALSO
>
> `bash`(1)
>
> ### IMPLEMENTATION
>
> GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)
>       Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>       License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later

You can see the arguments are optional. So

`cd &` is processed as
`cd` and then send to background. When `cd` is called with no argument no processing is needed. So it goes to background as "done" (processed).

Some info regarding `&`
The Bash `&` (ampersand) is a builtin control operator used to fork processes. From the Bash man page, "If a command is terminated by the control operator `&`, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell".

If logged into an interactive shell, the process is assigned a job number and the child PID is displayed. The job number below is one.

```
bash$ sleep 30 &
[1] 3586
```

Note that when a process is forked, the child PID is stored in the special variable `$!`

```
bash$ echo $!
3586
```

You can terminate the job by its job number like so:

```
bash$ jobs
[1]+ Running sleep 30 &
bash$ kill %1
[1]+ Terminated sleep 30
bash$
```

Comment: Close, but not quite. First, it's not that `cd` is run and then sent to the background. The background process is actually created before the program runs in the case of a regular command; in the case of a built-in, this behavior is emulated. The command gets run by this background process, replacing it. Second, `cd` without arguments *does* do something: it takes you to your `HOME` directory. But, since you've forked it off into the background, there is no effect in this case.

Comment: @WarrenYoung from the manpage it says cd  will take the home directory if no value is assigned to it. Upon sucessful directory change doesnt it recieve the value of $pwd?

Comment: The *background process*'s current working directory gets affected, not the foreground Bash shell's.